# Fetch value from multiple drop down with same name row wise

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a table like below-

[image]

the code of this table in my view is as following-

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
   <td>Course Name</td>
   <td>Class</td>
   <td>Subject Name</td>
   <td>Month</td>
   <td>View</td>
   </tr>
   <?php if(!empty($data)) { $i=1; foreach($data as $key => $value) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->course_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->class_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->subjectName; ?></td>
        <td><select class="form-control" id="month" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-error-message="Please Select Class">
             <option value="" hidden="hidden">Select Month</option>
             <option value="1">January</option>
             <option value="2">Febuary</option>
             <option value="3">March</option>
             <option value="4">April</option>
             <option value="5">May</option>
             <option value="6">June</option>
             <option value="7">July</option>
             <option value="8">August</option>
             <option value="9">September</option>
             <option value="10">October</option>
             <option value="11">November</option>
             <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
           <button id="<?php echo $i;?>" class="form-control" data-eid="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('e_id');?>"                                                data-subjectid="<?php echo $value->subjectId;?>" data-courseid="<?php echo $value->course_id;?>" data-classid="<?php echo $value->class_id;?>">
     View</button></td>
 </tr>
  <?php $i++; } } ?>
  </table>
```

//javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').on('click',function(){
   var eid = $(this).data('eid');
   var subId = $(this).data('subjectid');
   var courseId = $(this).data('courseid');
   var classId = $(this).data('classid');
   var month = $('#month').val();
   if(month == '')
    alert("Select Month");
   else { alert("okay"); }       
</script>
```

Whenever I select `month` and click the `view` button the page is redirected correctly, but when I select `month` in the second row and click the `view` button again it gives alert `select month`.

I don't know how to differentiate all the dropdowns based on a name.

Comment: you need to use `$(this)` and `closest` which will give you month valye linked with that button

Comment: `id` duplication of `#month`. Use class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're repeating the same `id` attributes in the elements you create in the loop. These need to be unique within the DOM.

To fix the issue you need to change the `id` to `class`. Then you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find the month `select` which is in the same row as the button which was clicked. To do that use `closest()` to get the parent `tr`, then `find()`:

```html
<select class="form-control month" data-parsley-required="true" ... >
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var eid = $(this).data('eid');
  var subId = $(this).data('subjectid');
  var courseId = $(this).data('courseid');
  var classId = $(this).data('classid');

  var month = $(this).closest('tr').find('.month').val();
  if (month == '')
    alert("Select Month");
  else 
    alert("okay");  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by looping select with name attribute. something like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#show").on('click',function(){
    $("select[name='car']").each(function(){
          var car=$(this).val();
          console.log(car);
    })
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td><select name='car'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td><select name='car'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='show' value='showname'/>
```